# How would I resolve this error?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am currently writing code for a program that, when it works, opens an external window that has a building and a scrolling banner on it. If you input a phrase into a textbox above the building, that phrase will scroll across the banner.

DisplayWindow

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DisplayWindow extends JFrame {
    private Container c;

    public DisplayWindow() {
       super("Display");
       c = this.getContentPane();
    }

    public void addPanel(JPanel p) {
       c.add(p);
    }

    public void showFrame() {
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

MovingSignPanel

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 public class MovingSignPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
 JMenuBar b;
 JButton start = new JButton("Start");
 JButton stop = new JButton("Stop"); 
 JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
 JTextField phrase = new JTextField(20);
 private int lVar = 200;
 private int rVar = 600;
 private int hVar = 200;
 private int ground = 400;
 private Timer scroll = new Timer(40,this);
 private int xVel = 2;
 private int xVal = lVar;
 private int yVal = 150;
 private String input = " ";
 private int inputWidth = 0;
 private Boolean scrolling = false;


 public MovingSignPanel(JMenuBar b){
     setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
     setBackground(Color.white);
     this.add(phrase);
     phrase.addActionListener(this);
     this.add(start);
     start.addActionListener(this);
     this.add(stop);
     stop.addActionListener(this);
     this.add(quit);
     quit.addActionListener(this);
 }


 public void drawBanner(Graphics g){
     clearBanner(g);
     drawBuilding(g);
     int position = xVal;
     while(position < rVar){
        g.drawString(input,position,yVal);
        position += inputWidth;
     }
     position = xVal - inputWidth;
     while(position > lVar - inputWidth){
        g.drawString(input,position,yVal);
        position -= inputWidth;
     }
     if(xVal > rVar)
       xVal -= inputWidth;
     xVal += xVel;
     drawBuilding(g);
}

public void drawBuilding(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0,0,1000,1000);
    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillRect(lVar,200,rVar-lVar,hVar);
    g.fillRect(lVar,100,rVar-lVar,hVar-800);
    g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    g.fillRect(0, ground, 700, 400 - ground);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    for(int n = lVar + 20; n < rVar - 10; n += 40){
        for(int m = 60; m < 150; m += 30){
            g.fillRect(n,m,20,20);
        }
    }
    for(int n = lVar + 20; n < rVar - 10; n += 40){
        for(int m = 210; m < 350; m += 30){
            g.fillRect(n,m,20,20);
        }
    }
    g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
    g.fillRect(0,0,lVar,ground);
    g.fillRect(rVar,0,lVar,ground);
}

public void inputMsg(){
   input = phrase.getText();
    inputWidth = phrase.getText().length();
}

public void resetTimer(){
   scroll.stop();
   scrolling = false;
}

public void startMsg(){
    inputMsg();
    if(!scrolling){
        scroll.start();
        scrolling = true;
    }
}  

public void clearBanner(Graphics g){
   g.clearRect(0,0,1000,1000);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() == quit)
        System.exit(0);
    if (e.getSource() == start)
        repaint();
        startMsg();
    if (e.getSource() == stop)
        resetTimer();
}
}
```

SignDriver

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SignDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DisplayWindow d = new DisplayWindow();
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        d.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        MovingSignPanel p = new MovingSignPanel(menuBar);
        d.addPanel(p);
        d.showFrame();
    }
}
```

I can organize this better if needed. I know the buttons don't work yet, but right now I'm more concerned with why nothing is being drawn when the program is run. The error occurs whenever I try to run the program and looks like this:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: MovingSignPanel.<init>(Ljavax/swing/JMenuBar;)V
at SignDriver.main(SignDriver.java:9)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when the program is run"? How are you compiling/deploying?

Comment: After compiling the program, it does not run successfully.

Comment: Compiling how? Do you use the IDE or do you manually compile the classes using javac?

Comment: I compile it using the IDE

Comment: _"I can organize this better if needed."_ - Don't ask just do it from the start. No one wants to look at improperly indented code. I did it for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

Seems your `SignDriver` class at runtime has an old version of the class `MovingSignPanel`, a version that does not have this constructor `MovingSignPanel(javax.swing.JMenuBar)`. Just try to clean and rebuild, and this error should disappear.

Comment: In this assignment, I cannot alter the SignDriver class. I'm not so much looking for a direct answer, but where would I go about cleaning my code up so that SignDriver is compatible with MovingSignPanel. I'd just like to understand why this is happening for future reference.

Comment: OK, well, you rather need to recompile the MovingSignPanel and deploy it where it's needed at runtime. The problem is that at runtime the version of MovingSignPanel.class is not up-to-date. This is what I think based on the error you posted here.

Comment: What I've surmised is that the problem is found in the MovingSignPanel class, where the MovingSignPanel method declares a JMenuBar object. It seems like SignDriver does not know what to do with that.

Comment: No, the problem is here: `SignDriver.java:9`. This line of the code calls a constructor of `MovingSignPanel`. The thing is that this constructor even though it is in your Java code (text file) is not in your bytecode (class file) for `MovingSignPanel`. The JRE does not execute your text file but your class file. If that one does not match your text file, then it's your responsibility to rebuild the text file and redeploy it so that the new version of the class file is visible at runtime to the JRE.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, thank you. I'll try and figure it out.